# Why do wee need to put one more layer and where is the softmax activation function?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm reading and testing the basic example of CNN from TensorFlow tutorial web site:

The model from the tutorial looks:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')  

model.add(layers.Flatten())

#  1.why do we need the next line ? 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

Two basic questions:

1. We are building CNN network.
   Why do we need the last layer (`model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))`) ?
   It is not part of the CNN network, and from my tests, I'm getting same results (accuracy) with or without this last layer
2. In the tutorial they wrote that they used softmax in the last layer:

   "CIFAR has 10 output classes, so you use a final Dense layer with 10 outputs and a softmax activation"

   but they didn't use softmax in their code.

   I checked the documentation, and the default activation function is `None` and not softmax. so the tutrial has a mistake and it is not used with softmax ?

[Convolutional Neural Network (CNN)](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CNN consist of (conv-pool)<sub>n</sub>-(flatten or globalpool)-(Dense)<sub>m</sub>, where the (conv-pool)<sub>n</sub> part extracts the features from a 2D signal and (Dense)<sub>m</sub> selects the features from the previous layers.

The output of the last layer is (4,4,64) which are 64 feature maps of size 4 × 4 (2D signals). We then flattens them to get a 4 × 4 × 64=1024 dim vector (instead, we can also use global max/avg pool to get a 64 dim vector). If you are using flatten then it will yield a 1024 dime vector and we have 10 classes. This will drastically reduce the dimension, leading to loss of important features. This is known as 'representation bottleneck'. To avoid this you can insert a Dense layer with (say 64 neuron) which will first project 1024 dim vector → 64 dim vector and then from 64 dim → 10 dim vector. If you use global max/ avg pooing then you can skip the additional Dense layer. In your case it seems that the representational bottleneck is avoided.

2. The tutorial is using

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Tensorflow has efficient implementation for logits calculation. This way, you need not use softmax in the layer. It will automatically optimize it as if you used softmax.

But if you still wish to use softmax in the Dense layer then you can use it. but then in the compile() use `from_logits=False`.  However, the later approach is less efficient as it requires double work.

Answer (score 1):

1. The purpose of a dense layer or a fully connected layer before the final dense layer is to give weights or it votes to select the most appropriate label before selecting in the final layer. In this case of the image below adding a few more neurons to select the label cat [image]

Check this link out for a deeper understanding of fc layers: https://missinglink.ai/guides/convolutional-neural-networks/fully-connected-layers-convolutional-neural-networks-complete-guide/

2. A softmax layer typically maps the predictions(logits) into a more understandable format where's each value in the tensor can add up to become 1

```
[1.6e-7, 1.6e-8, 1.6e-9, 1.6e-10] # Before applying softmax
[0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1] # After applying softmax
```

Note: The typical way of using the predictions is getting the highest value with the tensor

```py
import numpy as np
preds = model.predict(batch_data)
highest_val = np.argmax(preds) # returns an index, in this case 0
```